# Merge Metal tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are currently three tags on the main site about Metal for iOS, introduced by Apple on WWDC14. These are:

- [metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metal) (4 questions)
- [metal-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metal-framework) (8 questions)
- [apple-metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-metal) (2 questions)

I think they should be merged into [metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metal), which would then be consistent with tags for similar frameworks like [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl) or [directx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directx).

Of course, I could retag them to [metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metal), but then they would probably simply pop up in the review queues, as I don't have 2k rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only questions in [metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metal) were about Apple's Metal implementation, I made [metal-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metal-framework) and [apple-metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-metal) synonyms of that tag. If this becomes a problem later on, we can think about how it would be made less ambiguous, but this seems fine now.

Comment: We learned with the [pig question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575) that tags should be unambiguous since the start.